# How do I properly add a scrollbar to a jQuery Mobile popup using iScrollview?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, iscrollview

I am working on a webpage using jQuery Mobile, iScrollview, and Google Maps. When the map gets initialized, it will load a set of markers with infowindows containing an image. When the image gets clicked, it will load the content of a jQM popup with a list and show the popup.

I am having 2 problems:

1) How can I set a height (e.g. 150px) for my jQM popup's content? Using iScrollview, the content's height becomes overridden and becomes large. Using the [refresh()](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview#refreshing) as specified in the documentation has no effect (or am I using it wrong?).

2) Is there a way for me to show a scrollbar only if the list exceeds the height of the content? Currently, it always shows a scrollbar.

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="header" data-role="header">
            <h1>Products</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content" data-role="content" data-iscroll>
    </div>
        <div class="footer" data-role="footer">
            <a class="close" href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup {
    width: 175px;
}
.popup .content {
    height: 150px; /* has no effect */
    padding: 10px;
}
.popup .content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
} 
.popup .content ul li {
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var markers = [];

function addMarker(i, retailer) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(retailer.lat, retailer.lng),
        products: retailer.products // array of strings of unknown length
    });

    var infobox = new InfoBox({
        boxClass: 'infobox',
        closeBoxURL: '',
        content: '\
            <img class="detail" src="img/arrow_light.png" alt="" onclick="openPopup('+ parseInt(i) +');" />\
            <div class="name"><span>' + retailer.name + '</span></div>\
            <div class="address"><span>' + retailer.address + '</span></div>\
            <div class="arrow"></div>',
        maxWidth: 500,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -110)
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}

function openPopup(i) {
    var items = [];
    // create list
    $.each(markers[i].products, function(i, name) {
        items.push('<li>' + name + '</li>');
    });
    // set popup's content
    $('.popup .content')
        .empty()
        .append('<ul class="list">' + items.join('') + '</ul>')
        .iscrollview('refresh');
    // show popup
    $('.popup').popup({ history: false, transition: 'pop' }).popup('open');
}
```

Comment: for q1: `$('.popup').on('popupafteropen', function () { $(thi).find('.content').height(150); });` for q2: `if($('.contents_selector').height() > 150) { $('.contents_selector').css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); }` something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing you need to do is override popup content height and inforce it like this:

```
.ui-popup .ui-content {
    height: 150px !important;
}
```

Remember to use !important if you want to override class css. !important is only needed when working with classes. For example if you initialize your css through id (#) !important is not needed.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/N28Vg/